# Any example of this kind of ring, different from $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: ring-theory

I'm looking for an example of this kind of ring:
I need a ring $R$ with at least two elements, such that for all $a\in R^*$, there exists a unique $b\in R^*$ such that $aba=a$, different from $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Without the uniqueness of the element there is $\mathbb{H}$. But the unicity makes it hard to find that ring.

Comment: Is $R^*$ supposed to be $R\setminus{\{0\}}$ ? If so, then every field has this property (take $b = a^{-1}$).

Comment: Thanks. And one that isn't a field?

Comment: Pick any commutative (von Neumann) [regular ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring) $\not\cong \Bbb Z_2\ $

Comment: Ohhh, thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: if for each nonzero $a$ there is a unique nonzero $b$ such that $aba=a$, 
then such a ring has no zero divisors, for if $ax=0$ then $a(b-x)a=a$ implies $x=0$
using the uniqueness. It is also true that $R$ has an identity, so it is a division ring. If in addition, $R$ is commutative then $R$ is a field.

Comment: @Lozenges Yes, that and more is already mentioned in the linked Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am assuming you require an identity for the ring.)

I can't tell since you don't address your response explicitly, but it looks like you may have been taken in by Bill Dubuque's incorrect assertion that "any other commutative VNR ring works." It is apparently a misreading of what is in the wiki.

As Lozenges has demonstrated in the comments, such a ring has no zero divisors:

> ... for if $ax=0$ then $a(b−x)a=a$ implies $x=0$ using the uniqueness. (...) it is a division ring

It's a division ring since each nonzero ideal contains a nonzero idempotent, and a nonzero idempotent that isn't a zero divisor must be the identity.

So you can only look among division rings.

If $aba=a$ for a nonzero $a$, then solving for $b$ proves that $b=a^{-1}$, so the $b$ is unique. So the division rings are precisely what you need. Just pick one other than $F_2$.